# Swift Sprite-kit: Contact not registered after user interaction to move object

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

So I am having an issue with Swift Sprite-kit. Contact is not being registered. This has something to do with my code for moving a row of objects. I have code in the `touchesBegan` method that finds the user's touch location, and then a block of code in the `touchesMoved` method that then recognises a drag on the screen and moves the row correspondingly. I know that the `touchesMoved` function works because the row moves when the user drags the screen.

Here is the code for my `touchesBegan` method:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    if gameOver == 0 {

        var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        var touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)


        if let body = physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(touchLocation) {
            if body.node == self {
                //if touchLocation == blueBox.position {
                isFingerOnScreen = true
            }
        }
```

And this is my code for the `touchesMoved`

```
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    // 1. Check whether user touched the screen
    if isFingerOnScreen == true {
        // 2. Get touch location
        var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        var touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var previousLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)

        // 4. Calculate new position along x for objects
        var blueBoxX = blueBox.position.x + (touchLocation.x - previousLocation.x)
        var greenBoxX = greenBox.position.x + (touchLocation.x - previousLocation.x)
        var redBoxX = redBox.position.x + (touchLocation.x - previousLocation.x)
        var yellowBoxX = yellowBox.position.x + (touchLocation.x - previousLocation.x)

        // 5. Limit x so that the objects won't leave screen to left or right (this code does not actually work for me)
        /*
        blueBoxX = max(blueBoxX, blueBox.size.width/2)
        blueBoxX = min(blueBoxX, size.width - blueBox.size.width/2)

        greenBoxX = max(greenBoxX, greenBox.size.width/2)
        greenBoxX = min(greenBoxX, size.width - greenBox.size.width/2)

        redBoxX = max(redBoxX, redBox.size.width/2)
        redBoxX = min(redBoxX, size.width - redBox.size.width/2)

        yellowBoxX = max(yellowBoxX, yellowBox.size.width/2)
        yellowBoxX = min(yellowBoxX, size.width - yellowBox.size.width/2)
        */

        // 6. Update object position
        blueBox.position = CGPointMake(blueBoxX, blueBox.position.y)
        blueBox.zPosition = 10


        greenBox.position = CGPointMake(greenBoxX, greenBox.position.y)
        greenBox.zPosition = 10
        greenBox.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(greenBox.size.width, greenBox.size.height * 1/100))
        greenBox.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
        greenBox.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = greenColourGroup


        redBox.position = CGPointMake(redBoxX, redBox.position.y)
        redBox.zPosition = 10

        yellowBox.position = CGPointMake(yellowBoxX, yellowBox.position.y)
        yellowBox.zPosition = 10

    }
```

Now this is all good so far but my issue is that when this code is active, it for some reason stops the app from recognising contact between a ball and an object. Whereas when the code is commented out, the contact is recognised and the objects match. This makes no sense to me because as far as I can tell the only thing I am changing with the `greenBox` object (the only object I am testing with) is the position of the object in relation to the `touchLocation`. 
My code for the contact is as follows:

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
    switch contactMask {

    case greenColourGroup | ballColourGroup:

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == greenColourGroup || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == greenColourGroup {
             if ballColourGroup == greenColourGroup {


                score++

                scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"

                ball.removeFromParent()

                makeBall()
```

I am quite new to coding and am really struggling with this issue, so please help and if it involves code please include the necessary code needed to fix this issue.

Thanks

P.S: Just to confirm, the `didBeginContact` method works perfectly when the code for moving the objects is commented out, so I know that this code is ok. The issue is that the code within the `touchesMoved` method is stopping it from working

Comment: try to remove the physics body of node on "touchesBegan" if you are changing position or frame of  node. Then add again on ended.

Comment: Do you mean add this code: `greenBox.physicsBody = nil` on `touchesBegan` and then add the physicsBody back in at the end of `touchesMoved`?